# Rails 4 asset or image path from CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

my file structure is like so

```
app
  assets
    bookshelf
      assets
        my_image.jpg
    images
      standard_image.png
```

In my css.scss file, both of these work in development, but they don't work in production.

```
#some_div {
  background: url("standard_image.png")
}


#some_div {
  background: url("assets/my_image.jpg")
}
```

I've done `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile`. I've deleted my `tmp/cache`.

I feel like this may be a config problem. What am I missing?

I know the images is on the server. I got the digested file name and put it into the url with the production root address.

---

When I try to use

```
      background: asset-url("assets/my_image.jpg", image)
```

I get

> Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetFilteredError at /books
>
> Asset filtered out and will not be served: add
>   `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
>   assets/bookshelf_skin02_top_bg.jpg )` to
>   `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Obviously, I don't want to add each asset file in the config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created `/config/initializers/asset.rb` and put the relevant file extensions in regex form.

I believe this works because this tells the asset pipeline to precompile all of these file types in lib or vendor, which aren't done automatically in rails 4.

```
# Images
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)\z/

# Fonts
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove assets folder :

`background: image-url('my_image.jpg');`

Comment: this will work for files in the image folder only, not in custom folders within `vendor/assets` or `lib/assets`

Answer (score 0):

Set true in your config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: I know that will work, but it's a good idea because of speed. There is another way.